# Reduce size of .obj file significantly

Tags: 3d

I am not expert in using 3D modelling tools/softwares. Hence, I am not sure how to even explain this to a 3D designer. The OBJ file that I get is huge, when the `.glTF`/`.glb` file that I get is only 5MB the `.obj` file is 390MBs. I am especially surprised with the difference in the file sizes between these 2 file formats!

How can we reduce the file size of the `.obj` file?
What should I ask the 3D designer to do to reduce the file size?
Or is there an application/tool available that can help reduce this without significantly effecting its quality?

Answer (score 0):

OBJ file is a text file format while .glTF and .glb are binary file formats. The only way to reduce (a little) the OBJ file size is to remove all unnecessary spaces. This can be done simply with a text editor and the find and replace command.

Here are more details on the .glTF file format: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/specification/1.0/README.md