# How to reduce obj files programatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, 3d-model

I want to reduce size of my obj files programatically in swift.

There is similar question/s asked previously, but it's not helping me out.

[Reduce size of .obj file significantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61398673/reduce-size-of-obj-file-significantly)

Does anyone have any idea how to do that in swift

Comment: Compile in Swift with `-Osize` option - this will reduce code speed but will make much smaller binaries sizes. This is so colled optimize-by-size option. Also you have to remove other `-O...` options if they are present on command line.

Comment: @Arty I don't think they are asking about compiled object files `.o`. They are asking about the 3D model file format `.obj`. Totally different things.

Comment: @Sweeper yes you are right. I am asking about the 3d model files. do you have idea?

Comment: Did you try what the other answer suggested? Did you remove all unnecessary formatting to reduce the size?

Comment: Yes but no solution found. Any suggestions on how to remove unnecessary formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Depends what's the reason why you need reduction. If you care about occupied disk storage or care about transfer speed via network, then best is to compress it, as `.obj` is a text format you can gain great compression.

I suggest using [Zstandard](http://facebook.github.io/zstd/) compressor/archiver, for three reasons:

1. It has great compression ratio, close to LZMA (7-zip) compression ratio.
2. Its decompression speed is up to `1000-2000 MBytes/sec`. Decompression speed doesn't depend on compression level used.
3. It [has API](https://github.com/facebook/zstd) for compression/decompression, which is ported to many languages, including Swift. Hence you can incorporate into your Swift program decompression on the fly of input `.obj.zst` files.

To compress with it from command line at maximal compression level just do:

```
zstd -v --ultra -22 --long=30 model.obj -o model.obj.zst
```

Also if you're not going to open `.obj.zst` inside Swift program, but going to use it with some other program, then if such program allows input from STDIN stream then you can just pipe zstd decompression to this program:

```
zstd -dc model.obj.zst | some_program.exe
```

Comment: But this is not working for .obj files. do you have any example or demo?

Comment: @FAAIZDAAG My answer suggested another approach. You want to reduce `.obj` files, but I suggested to compress/archive them. My answer depends on why you need reduction. If you just want to use less disk space or want to use less network bandwith to send your `.obj` files then my solution Works. But if you have other reasons for reductions then my solution is not what is needed. As suggested in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61398673/reduce-size-of-obj-file-significantly) mentioned by you, it is not possible to reduce size of `.obj` much except for cleaning white spaces.

Comment: @FAAIZDAAG If you're writing/reading `.obj` files from Your Swift program then you can easily use my solution by embedding [zstd API](https://github.com/facebook/zstd) inside your Swift program. Then you can read and write `.obj.zst` compressed files directly from your code. This way you will reduce stored-on-disk size of your object files. I'm repeating that my Answer's approach is totally different, it doesnt suggest how to reduce `.obj` but suggests how you can archive/de-archive them on the fly from your Swift code. My solution will give 4-7 times reduction of obj files.

Comment: yes it’s reducing the size, but I am developing an app which will reduce the size of 3d models(.obj or any 3d model ) files and give same reduced file.

Comment: @FAAIZDAAG Alright, if your App is meant only to reduce `.obj` file and doing nothing else then of course my `zstd` archiving solution is not for you. This solution is only meant for the case if you were developing App that USES the `.obj` file for example to render the model, then such App of course can benefit from reading archived version of `.obj.zst` file on the fly, especially if to take into account that Zstd can decompress on fly with speed `1000-2000 MBytes/sec`.